# Calling async function in main file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am creating App integrating two systems. Therefore, I am using some requests and async functions. It's no problem to call async function in async function. However, I need to end somehow this chain and call async function in my main file where is App served from.
Do you have any idea how to do it? Part of code looks like this

```js
async function asyncFunctionINeedToCall() {
  await childAsyncFunction()
}

asyncFunctionINeedToCall()
```

Comment: All async functions return a promise - that's how you do it

Comment: @boehm_s provided the correct answer below. You should accept it.

Answer (score 77):

Since the main scope is not `async`, you will need to do an async anonymous function that calls your function and itself :

```
(async function() {
  await yourFunction();
})();
```

Or resolve the promise :

```
yourFunction().then(result => {
  // ...
}).catch(error => {
  // if you have an error
})
```

Comment: Hi @Tripo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for an arrow function version of the async function that calls itself, here it is:

```
(async () => {
  await callAsyncFunction();
})();
```