# Wait for ssh-exec to finish

Tags: node.js, wait

Im trying to get information from remote host with the `ssh-exec` package.
So here is my function:

```
getHostStats(hostnames) {
    var currhost;
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(hostnames).length; i++) {
        currhost = hostnames[i];
        console.log("Current host: " + currhost);
        exec('/root/usage.sh', {
            user: 'root',
            host: currhost,
        },
            function (err, stdout) {
                if (err) { console.error(err); }
                result = stdout.split('\n');
                console.log("Hostname: " + currhost + ", Result 1: " + result[0] + ", Result 2: " + result[1]);
            }
        );

        console.log(result);
        this.setHostInfo(currhost, result);
    }
```

So my issue is, the command im running takes about 2 seconds to finish and return a result.
The commands:

```
console.log(result);
this.setHostInfo(currhost, result);
```

unfortunately dont wait for the `exec(...)` function to finish and because of this the variable `result` is empty and it returns `undefined`

So i read something about `await` and `async` but i have no idea how i can tell my app to wait for the `exec(...)` function to finish first and then log the result.

I know its possible but my dev-skills arent the best and i have really no idea how i can realize this.

**Other Question**: Does ssh-exec automatically close the connection after the command finished?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to use async/await

```js
function executeShhCommand (host) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec('/root/usage.sh', {
      user: 'root',
      host: host,
    }, (err, stdout) => {
      if (err) { 
        return reject(err) 
      }
      
      result = stdout.split('\n');
      resolve(result)      
    })
  })
}

async function getHostStats(hostnames) {
    for (const host of hostnames) {
      const results = await executeShhCommand(host)
      console.log('Results for', host)
      console.log(results)
      
      // other custom code
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey, with this code im recieving the following error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, isnt it needed to declare `executeSshcommand` as async function? EDIT: Sorry my fault, forgot to make `getHostStats` async. Will try it out and then tell you

Comment: It is not needed. `await` can wait for promises too.

Comment: You will need to enclose the invocation to `getHostStats` in a function. Will update the answer

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601634/91403 "Since the main scope is not async, you will need to do an async anonymous function that calls your function and itself :"

Comment: Yes, forgot the `async` keyword