# Jest , testing Asynchronous JS code always failing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I am trying to test my node app.js script in which I have an asynchronous request sendMessageRequest () to a function sendSmtpMessage() [ a Promise ]

**app.js**

```
    const sendSmtpMessage = require("./sendSmtpMessage.js");

    const keys = {....};
    const mailOptions = {...}

    const sendMessageRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await sendSmtpMessage(keys,mailOptions);
        console.log("... SEND MSG REQUEST FULLFILLED: ", result);
      } catch(err){
        console.log("... SEND MSG REQUEST FAILED: ");
      }
    };
    sendMessageRequest();
```

I wrote the following app.spec.js, according to doc on Testing asynchronous code ( with async/await); but I guess my sendSmtpMessage() mocking is wrong...

**app.spec.js**

```
jest.mock("../sendSmtpMessage.js");
const sendSmtpMessage = require("../sendSmtpMessage.js");
const app = require("../app.js");

// sendSmtpMessage is a mock function
sendSmtpMessage.mockImplementation(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      (oauth2ClientMock.refreshToken !== "undefined")? resolve() : reject()
      , 2000
    });
  })
});

describe('app', () => {
  let keys, mailOptions;
  beforeEach(() => {
    keys = {....};
    mailOptions = {....}
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    keys = {};
    mailOptions = {};
  });

  it("should call successfully sendMessageRequest", async () => {
    // GIVEN
    // WHEN
    // THEN
    expect.assertions(1);
    await expect(sendSmtpMessage).resolves.toBe("OK");
  });

  it("should call unsuccessfully sendMessageRequest", async () => {
    // GIVEN
    // WHEN
    keys.oauth.refresh_token = null;
    // THEN
    expect.assertions(1);
    await expect(sendSmtpMessage).rejects.toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

As the console.log output is showing errors on both expectations in each test ( on resolve and reject )

**console.log**

jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage "app.spec.js"

FAIL  test/app.spec.js
  app
    ✕ should call successfully sendMessageRequest (15ms)
    ✕ should call unsuccessfully sendMessageRequest (2ms)

● app › should call successfully sendMessageRequest

```
expect(received).resolves.toBe()

received value must be a Promise.
Received:
  function: [Function mockConstructor]

  52 |     // THEN
  53 |     expect.assertions(1);
> 54 |     await expect(sendSmtpMessage).resolves.toBe("OK");
     |                                            ^
  55 |   });
  56 |
  57 |   it("should call unsuccessfully sendMessageRequest", async () => {

  at Object.toBe (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:158:13)
  at Object.toBe (test/app.spec.js:54:44)
```

● app › should call successfully sendMessageRequest

```
expect.assertions(1)

Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

  51 |     // WHEN
  52 |     // THEN
> 53 |     expect.assertions(1);
     |            ^
  54 |     await expect(sendSmtpMessage).resolves.toBe("OK");
  55 |   });
  56 |

  at Object.assertions (test/app.spec.js:53:12)
```

● app › should call unsuccessfully sendMessageRequest

```
expect(received).rejects.toBeTruthy()

received value must be a Promise.
Received:
  function: [Function mockConstructor]

  61 |     // THEN
  62 |     expect.assertions(1);
> 63 |     await expect(sendSmtpMessage).rejects.toBeTruthy();
     |                                           ^
  64 |   });
  65 |
  66 | });

  at Object.toBeTruthy (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:203:13)
  at Object.toBeTruthy (test/app.spec.js:63:43)
```

● app › should call unsuccessfully sendMessageRequest

```
expect.assertions(1)

Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

  60 |     keys.oauth.refresh_token = null;
  61 |     // THEN
> 62 |     expect.assertions(1);
     |            ^
  63 |     await expect(sendSmtpMessage).rejects.toBeTruthy();
  64 |   });
  65 |

  at Object.assertions (test/app.spec.js:62:12)
```

Where am I wrong ? I don't understand very well the testing process of such plain js scripts... ( use to work with vue.js, test-utils ...)

thanks for feedback and eventually on any link to make me understanding the test unit in such case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not awaiting the sendMessageRequest method call itself

```
const sendSmtpMessage = require("./sendSmtpMessage.js");

        const keys = {....};
        const mailOptions = {...}

        const sendMessageRequest = async () => {
          try {
            const result = await sendSmtpMessage(keys,mailOptions);
            console.log("... SEND MSG REQUEST FULLFILLED: ", result);
          } catch(err){
            console.log("... SEND MSG REQUEST FAILED: ");
          }
        };

    (async function() {
      await sendMessageRequest();
    })();
```

Comment: But the sendMessageRequest() is oit of the async block... ?

Comment: ah yes, you are right, but that is causing your issue I believe, you will need to await that call otherwise it'll complete your test execution. Are you able to call into your app class externally to call this method and then you can wrap that in async/await?

Comment: I understand... this app.js script ( or can be naled : index. js or main.js ) is not a class ... it’s my main script executed as :  node app.js..

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601552/calling-async-function-in-main-file I'll update my answer  for you. You'll probably have the same issue though, because the wrapped function isn't awaited